# ¿Como restringir la funcion de un CSS?

Tags: javascript, html, css

*~estoy añadiendo una funcion multiselect en una pagina ya creada, que presenta si propio diseño y su propio css. el multiselect tambien presenta su propio diseño~*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*~en la imagen se puede ver que trabaja con dos direcciones de css, el styles.css es el de la pagina y bootstrap-multiselect.css es del que yo estoy añadiendo para darle diseño a mi opcion multiple.en la segunda imagen se puede mostrar la pagina si es que solo utilizara el codigo del multiselect y no el styles~*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*~el diseño del css lo estoy aplicando al select "tipo de manto torre" lo cual se puede ver en esta imagen y muestra los valores de una forma normal, sin espacio de linea, pero como se ve el diseño de toda la pagina es nula, ya que no tengo activado el css style.~*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

pero cuando añaqdo el diseño de la pagina(style.css), en el interfaz de ingreso no genera ningun problema...

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*~pero en el momento de ver los datos de manto se genera el conflicto, ya que se distorciona la forma de mostrar los valores y se crea un espacio grande de interlineado~*

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

*~entonces mi regunta seria si es que habria una restriccion para que el css de la pagina(style.css) no altere al selectMultiple(que esta creado dentro de un tabla en html)

Comment: Bienvenido te aconsejo crear que añadas tu código con las librerias .js y los estilos que usas con la herramienta (Ctrl+M) para que puedan ayudarte con mas facilidad.

Comment: claro @LeonardoCabré ... tambien tengo las librerias .js de bootstrap-multiselect , pero pasa lo mismo, estaba pensando que si es que se puede poner una clave a una tabla del html(ya que alli esta mi select MULTIPLE), y luego crear un codigo para que el style.css(diseño de la pag), no altere a mi tabla y el diseño del multiselect actue de manera libre

Answer (score 0):

Si, se puede, hay diferentes formas de hacerlo, una de las que suelo utilizar yo es agregarle una clase extra al componente ya utilizado global, por ejemplo: tengo estilos para `.multiselect {}`, entonces le agrego una nueva clase como `.multiselect.miselectpersonalizado {}` y aplico todos los cambios sobre ese elemento padre.

Supongamos que tenés armado lo siguiente de bootstrap:

```
.multiselect {}
.multiselect select {}
.multiselect select option {}
```

Entonces yo agrego los estilos nuevos pero dentro de una nueva clase:

```
.multiselect.miselectpersonalizado {}
.multiselect.miselectpersonalizado select {}
.multiselect.miselectpersonalizado select option {}
```

Y dentro del html:

```
<div class="multiselect miselectpersonalizado">
  <select>
    ...
  </select>
<div>
```

Comment: yo tengo descargado 3 librerias de bootstrap: bootstrap-multiselect.js, bootstrap-3.3.2.min.js y el bootstrap-multiselect.css ... entonces el .multiple.miselectpersonalizado donde lo aplicaria?

Comment: En un archivo `.css` nuevo. Siempre y cuando esté ubicado después de esos estilos de bootstrap así los pisa.

Comment: entonces crearia un archivo nuevo x.css en el cual solo ingresaria ese codigo de 3 lineas que usted escribio y luego la direccion lo añadiria en el head, pero tiene que ir deespues de los otras dos direcciones...verdad?

Comment: Si, en cuanto a las 3 líneas es subjetivo, vos ahí tenés que reemplazar con el diseño que agregaste para ese *multiselect*.

Comment: mmmmm... pero el diseño es una libreria, osea es el bootstrap-multiselect.min.css

Comment: es que no le entendi que es lo que iria en el archivo .css .... lo que si entendi es lo que tengo que hacer en el html

Comment: Aah! Entonces puede ser que esa librería `bootstrap-multiselect.min.css` sea compatible con la versión de bootstrap que tenés porque puede ser que tengas diferente versión entonces tiene diferente estructura de css.

Comment: claro, pero con respecto a css el bootstrap.multiselect.min.css es el unico que estoy usando

Comment: Podrás adjuntar todo lo que has hecho en un [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/) como para que pueda visualizar lo que hiciste y darte una mejor respuesta?

Comment: con respecto a la idea que me implementas, entonces en un nuevo .css añadiria las 3 lineas que me muestras y añadiria el contenido de lo que hay dentro del bootstrap-multiselect.min.css?

Comment: Como te dije, es subjetivo, puse eso como ejemplo. La idea es que allí pongas los estilos del tag. Podría explicarte mejor si compartes lo que hiciste.

Comment: es que es una pagina tan extensa, que tengo muchos restricciones para exportar, podrias plantear un ejemplo sencillo de como elaboraria ese nuevo .css